# TypeError: v.context.$implicit is not a function

Tags: typescript, ionic2

I'm new to Typescript.It has been 3 days.I want to access the data from Firebase.And I access and list. I get an error when I want to pass to another page with  (Click) ="item ()".Where am I doing wrong.

**data-api.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http,Response} from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
@Injectable()

export class DataApi {


 private url = 'https://ionic2-9dc0a.firebaseio.com/.json';   // https://ionic2-9dc0a.firebaseio.com

 currentphone : any = {};
constructor(private http:Http){
}
  getAdress(){
    return new Promise(resolve =>{
      this.http.get(`${this.url}`) 
      .subscribe(res => resolve(res.json()))
    });
  }





  }
```

**about.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'; 
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import {DataApi} from '../../app/shared/shared';
import {Http, HttpModule} from '@angular/http';


import  {TeamsPage} from '../teams/teams';

 @IonicPage()
 @Component({
 selector: 'page-about',
 templateUrl: 'about.html',
  })
 export class AboutPage {

 names: any;
 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, 
 public dataApi:DataApi, public http:Http) {

 }

 item(){
    this.navCtrl.push(TeamsPage);
  }

 ionViewDidLoad(){
    this.dataApi.getAdress().then(data => this.names= data[0]);
    console.log("willloaded");


   }


}
```

**about.html**

```
   <ion-header>

   <ion-navbar>
   <ion-title>Select Tournament </ion-title>
   </ion-navbar>

   </ion-header>


  <ion-content>
     <ion-list>    
       <button ion-item *ngFor="let item of names" (click)="item()">
         <h2> {{item.name}}</h2>
       </button>
     </ion-list>

 </ion-content>
```

**data.json**

```
 [
 [
{
  "id": 15,
  "name": "Sahne Sistemleri",
  "image": "sahne/1.jpg",

   {

     "image": "sahne/1.jpg"
   }

},
{
  "id": 16,
  "name": "Görüntü Sistemleri",
  "image": "sahne1/1.jpg"
},
{
  "id": 17,
  "name": "Podyum Sistemleri",
  "image": "sahne2/1.jpg"
},
{
  "id": 18,
  "name": "Masa, Sandalye ve Loca Grupları",
  "image": "sahne3/1.jpg"
},
{
  "id": 19,
  "name": "Çadır Sistemleri",
  "image": "sahne4/1.jpg"
},
{
  "id": 20,
  "name": "Mobil Jenaratör Hizmetleri",
  "image": "sahne5/1.jpg"
},
{
  "id": 21,
  "name": "Simultane(Çeviri) Sistemleri",
  "image": "sahne6/1.jpg"
}
]
]
```

**aboutpage**

[image]

Click on one of the items

**teampage**
[image]

Comment: Is `TeamsPage` also an `IonicPage`?

Comment: yes, IonicPage @suraj

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `TeamsPage` is an IonicPage, it is lazyloaded.

Check [IonicPage](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/IonicPage/).
Avoid importing `TeamsPage` in other pages. In order to push the page,
use the string equivalent of the page.
eg:

```
item(){
    this.navCtrl.push('TeamsPage');
  }
```

and remove the import.

**Or** if you want to use a custom string, set it in decorator in `TeamsPage`.

```
@IonicPage({
  name:'teams-page'
})
```

and while pushing the page,

```
   item(){
        this.navCtrl.push('teams-page');
      }
```

Secondly, your function name `item()` seems to clash with your for loop variable `item`.
Change it to:

```
   <button ion-item *ngFor="let n of names" (click)="item()">
      <h2> {{n.name}}</h2>
   </button>
```

Comment: I have made such a passage. My problem continues. It works when you remove ngFor from About.html, is there a problem with NgFor? I really do not understand what the problem is? <button ion-item   (click)="item()"> @suraj

Comment: change the function name.. your loop item and function name must be clashing

Answer (score 5):

It's very easy you need to just change your method name inside HTML because in your *ngFor iterator you have used same loop name and method name ..!

```
 <button ion-item *ngFor="let **item** of names" (click)="**item**()">
     <h2> {{item.name}}</h2>
   </button>
```