# Binding to a function result of a class in Angular

Tags: angular

In Angular it's simple to bind to class variable, for example:

```
<tr *ngFor="let team of teams">
    <th scope="row">{{team.name}}</th>
```

However I would like to bind to a function from a class instead of a variable like so:

```
<td>{{ team.getPoints() }}</td>
```

Unfortunately I get an error back in my browser:

> ERROR TypeError: "_v.context.$implicit.getPoints is not a function"

My Team class looks like this:

```
export class Team {
    name: string;
    results: Array<Result>;

    getPoints = function() {
        return 0; //STUB: to be calculated
    };
}
```

I don't have much experience with current Angular, but this should be dead simple to me. Why can't I bind to that function?

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring your function the wrong way.

It's not:

```
getPoints = function() {
    return 0; //STUB: to be calculated
};
```

It should be:

```
getPoint() {
    return "Test";
}
```

How about this solution?. Hope it helps!

```
<td>{{ getPoints() }}</td>
```

What you're trying to do is called ***string interpolation***.

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fkjaqr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Sadly, it's still a similar error.

ERROR TypeError: "_co.getPoints is not a function"

Comment: @HoppyKlaus I created a live demo for you where I don't get any errors. Hope it helps. Here's the link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fkjaqr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @HoppyKlaus your issue is that you are declaring your function the wrong way. Please take a look at my updated solution.

Comment: Even with the function declared as you have it I wind up with.

ERROR TypeError: "_v.context.$implicit.getPoints is not a function"

Comment: @HoppyKlaus I'm not sure what the structure of your app is, but as I showed you in the Live Demo. I don't get any errors.

Comment: @HoppyKlaus  Maybe this link will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43501592/typeerror-v-context-implicit-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 0):

because in array is array, don't function, should you can't for {{team.getPoints()}}, only {{team.name}}
You can use try the following code below!

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
     check : string;
    games : [{
        game: string,
        platform : string,
        release : string
    }];
    constructor(){
        this.check="OK";
        this.games = [{
            game : "Deus Ex: Mankind Divided",
            platform: " Xbox One, PS4, PC",
            release : "August 23"
        },
        {
            game : "Hue",
            platform: " Xbox One, PS4, Vita, PC",
            release : "August 23"
        },
        {
            game : "The Huntsman: Winter's Curse",
            platform: "PS4",
            release : "August 23"
        },
        {
            game : "The Huntsman: Winter's Curse",
            platform: "PS4",
            release : "August 23"
        }];

    };
    getPoint(){
       return this.check;
    }
}
```

```html
<tr *ngFor="let game of games; let i = index">
   <td> {{game.game}}</td>
   <td>{{getPoint()}}</td>

</tr>
```